# Color Coding background for different types of climate conditions

Tags: c++, background, directx, 3d

I am working on a C++ application under Visual Studio 2003 using DirectX 8.1 that uses 3D graphics to displays various elements. For Eg: I have a beach ball on a sunny day. I am able to draw the ball using graphics, but I am interested in drawing the sunny day background using any available color code, or any other input I can have in order to execute this. At the moment, I have basic colored backgrounds implemented in my code, like from Black to white. What would be the best way to go about this executing and generating the climate background through the code? Hope someone can help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exist many hacks and physically based methods, a definitive answer is not really possible. Some methods have good performance, but only give RGB data and work for clear day skies, other methods or for night skies only, and others generate full spectra, but suffer performance. So it depends.

A good overview for anything terrain related is http://vterrain.org, in your case:

- http://vterrain.org/Atmosphere/
- http://vterrain.org/Atmosphere/Clouds/
- http://vterrain.org/Atmosphere/rain.html